# How to auto-refresh a page using ajax (and prevent an actual browser refresh)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, refresh

I am trying to append a small autofreshing javascript to a page that already has jQuery.

**I don't have control of the site**, so I can't add a simple script to the HTML that would appear after each refresh.

**I have to run the script in the console** otherwise the page will only refresh once.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
var x = function(){
  // reload the page
  jQuery('html').load(window.location.href);

  // recurse every 5 seconds
  setTimeout(x, 5000);
};

// init
x();
```

This is generating an `appendChild` error. I'm guessing I'm just going about this a bit wrong.

Comment: You are trying to inject a page inside HTML Tag, exactly like appending child HTML. use `location.reload()` instead, this will reloads the page once, and if you want it recursively then try simpl JS like ` window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000);`. Hope this helps you......

Comment: Maybe I don't get the idea, but it seems to me that you need something called "injection". You can use [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/bg/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) for Mozilla FF or an equivalent for Chrome.

Comment: no, this doesn't help because the script must be run through the console.  Your solution and everyone other one posted is using `reload()` which wipes out any scripts I appended through the console after the first refresh :(

Comment: @Bakudan, my response was for Chiller.  I don't know of a Greasemoneky equivalent for Chrome and I don't feel like installing Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite the lack of belief that this is possible, this solution, while not perfect, is certainly working quite well

```
(function x(){
  jQuery('html').html('<iframe width="100%" height="' + $(window).height() + 'px" src="' + window.location.href + '"></iframe>');

  setTimeout(x, 5000);
})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function x(){
    setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);
}();
```

Edit: You've made your question a little more clear. This should do the trick:

```
setInterval(function(){ location.reload(); }, 5000);
```

Comment: Elliot, this fails for the same reason SKS's answer does.  Please see my comment on his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to replace the body with the contents of the page. It won't reload the whole page, so your script will stay right there. It could, however, conflict with existing scripts on the page.

How to do it:

```
var x = function () {
  $('body').load(window.location.pathname);

  setTimeout(x,5000);
}
x();
```

[jQuery Reference](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

edit:

and now a more 'syntatically not so awful' approach: rewrite the whole document.

```
var x = function () {
  $.get(window.location.pathname, function (data) { 
    document.open(); 
    document.write(data); 
    document.close(); } 
  );

  setTimeout(x,5000);
}
x();
```

This works and do not reload the page under the body tag.

But I think is too much typing and worries for an injection hack :P

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it's pretty syntactically awful to nest an HTML document directly in another one.  Scripts and CSS would be doubled up all within the same "namespace".  The `<iframe>` solution loads just as many resources, but at least keeps things separate.

Comment: ok, you have a point. I've just edited my answer to show how you really could actually reload the whole thing. It is possible, it is doable, and it works just fine :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `window.location.reload();` like below for an auto refresh script,

```
<script>
    setTimeout(function () {
       window.location.reload();
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: I initially thought that would work, but this is the same as refreshing the page manually.  It will only work for the first iteration.  After the reload, any script I sent in through the console gets cleared out :(

Comment: This will only refresh the page once with a 5-second delay.  **Note** I can't put this script in the HTML.  It must be entered in the javascript console.

Comment: @naomik I don't think it is possible. The script in the console has to be manually executed.